# PHP to count words from a txt file

Tags: php, html, ubuntu

i want to count the number of words in a text file. below is my code i have tried. The php code works fine but it is also counting the white spaces. what should i add in order for the code to not count the white-spaces.
My php code:

```
<?php 
$count = 0;  

//Opens a file in read mode  
$file = fopen("trial.txt", "r");  

//Gets each line till end of file is reached  
while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {  
    //Splits each line into words  
    $words = explode(" ", $line);  
    //Counts each word  
    $count = $count + count($words);  
}  

print("Number of words : " . $count);  
fclose($file);
?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need to reinvent the wheel. PHP has a built in function for counting words in a string: [str_word_count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php).

Using it in combination with [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents) to get the file contents, you can make the code way smaller.

This should do what you want:

```
$wordCount = str_word_count(file_get_contents('trial.txt'));
```